# How do i convert this forEach to forLoop

Tags: java, for-loop

Hey im trying convert all my ForEachs into ForLoops as i am now using a Linked List.
I am having trouble with this one for some reason! Anyone able to covert the forEach into a forLoop

```
public String listCounty(String county) {
    boolean matchFound = false;
    int i = 0;
    String displayPropertys = "All Propertys";

    for (Property item : house) {
        if (item.getGeneralLocation().equals(county)) {
            displayPropertys += "\n" + i++ + item;
            i++;
            matchFound = true;
        } else i++;
    }

    if (!matchFound)
        return "No propertys for this County";
    else
        return displayPropertys;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it using the following.

```
for(int index = 0; index < house.size(); index++)
{
    Property item = house.get(index);
    // Your code goes here
}
```

There's also no need for the i variable now that we have the index from the for loop.

```
public String listCounty(String county) {
    boolean matchFound = false;
    String displayPropertys = "All Propertys";

    for (int index = 0; index < house.length; index++) {
        Property item = house.get(index)
        if (item.getGeneralLocation().equals(county)) {
            displayPropertys += "\n" + (index + 1) + item;
            matchFound = true;
        } 
    }

    if (!matchFound)
        return "No propertys for this County";
    else
        return displayPropertys;
}
```

You can also use an iterator like Elliot suggests. This will give you better performance but is a bit more difficult to read.

```
Iterator<Property> iterator = house.iterator();
for (int index = 0; iterator.hasNext(); index++) {
    Property item = iterator.next();
    // Your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming house is a `LinkedList<Property>` you could use `LinkedList.get(int)` but it would be more efficient to use a traditional iterator (because accessing arbitrary indices of a `LinkedList` is potentially expensive). You could also use a `StringJoiner`. Something like,

```
public String listCounty(String county) {
    boolean matchFound = false;
    Iterator<Property> iter = house.iterator();
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(System.lineSeparator());
    sj.add("All Propertys");
    for (int i = 0; iter.hasNext(); i++) {
        Property item = iter.next();
        if (item.getGeneralLocation().equals(county)) {
            sj.add(String.format("%d%s", i + 1, item));
            matchFound = true;
        }
    }
    return !matchFound ? "No propertys for this County" : sj.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, I am assuming `house` is a `LinkedList`

```
for (int k = 0; k < house.size(); k++) {
    if (house.get(k).getGeneralLocation().equals(county)) {
        displayPropertys += "\n" + i++ + house.get(k);
        matchFound = true;
    } else i++;
}
```

Comment: Note... you have `i++` twice on *match*.